# Angular bootstrap ui modal scope binding with parent

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am having an Angular issue getting a modal scope to unbind from the parent scope.  I want the scope object I pass into the modal to be separate from the corresponding scope object.

No matter how I structure the modal object the parent always mirrors it.  The only solution I have found is to change the object property names, but that would be cumbersome to do for every modal in my project.

For example, I can have a $scope variable in the parent $scope.parentData.firstName and a modal variable $scope.modalData.a.b.c.firstName, and the parent will mirror the modal value.

I guess there is some parent child $scope issues here that I am not getting.
Here is a plunk illustrating the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/5naWXfkv7kmzFp7U2KPv?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                <input ng-model="modalData.a" />
                <input ng-model="modalData.b" />
                <input ng-model="modalData.c" />
            Selected: <b>{{ sourceData }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    {{sourceData}}
    <div ng-show="sourceData">Selection from a modal: {{ test }}</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.sourceData = {a:'abc',b:'bcd',c:'cde'};

  $scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        data: function () {
          return $scope.sourceData;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.scopeData = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
};

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, data) {
  $scope.modalData = {};
  $scope.modalData = data;

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.modalData);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

Comment: just use `angular.copy(object)`. Must remember that objects are passed by reference unless you clone them. This has nothing to do with angular, it is native javascript prototypical inheritance issue. After you modify the copy if you want to merge them back together again use `angular.extend()`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/jAo0c354puN17OX7Ysgl?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing a reference to your current object, what you want to do is use [`angular.copy()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to pass a deep copy of the object to the modal [***plnkr***](http://plnkr.co/edit/tsapGjgLDXhBn3DY25Bp?p=preview):

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
  resolve: {
    data: function () {
      return angular.copy($scope.sourceData); // deep copy
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: "$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.modalData);
  };" Is it the only function that can return data back to parent controller or there are other ways to do so ? Cheers!